# How can I trigger a (hover) event programatically?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is what I am using now. But when I call htmlElement.onmouseover() an error is shown where I am asked to put a mouseEvent as an argument. Any help is appreciated

```
 triggerFalseHover() {
      
        const htmlElement: HTMLElement = this.kendoButton.nativeElement;
        htmlElement.onmouseover();
      }

Error : htmlElement.onmouseover()
        onmouseover: ((this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: MouseEvent) => any) | null;
        An argument for 'ev' was not provided.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I use to trigger events is using the `dispatchEvent` method passing the intended event like showing in this demo:

```
const event = new Event('mouseover');
htmlElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

For further reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events